# How to use AudioContext in Chrome extension MV3

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, audiocontext

I am migrating my screen recorder chrome extension to MV3 but I have one issue. It is relate to AudioContext.
I showed it in below.
[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Vfo.png)

//background.js

```
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
```

Please help me :)
Best regards

Comment: You will use `chrome.offscreen` API once it's released, currently it's tested in Chrome Canary.